# Update statement SQL to increment date by 365 days

Tags: sql, mysql

I have two columns in my mysql db, end_date (example 9999-12-31) and start_date (example 2010-11-17), of type "DATE".

I want to do an update statement on the table such that if end_date = 9999-12-31, It will change the end_date to start_date + 365 days. But I only want it do update if end_date is 9999-12-31 (which essentially means no end date has been set)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
UPDATE sometable
SET end_date=DATE_ADD(start_date, INTERVAL 365 DAY)
WHERE end_date='9999-12-31'
```

Comment: I had a typo in my question. I believe your answer is right on, however, check my question again as I'm trying to change end_date, not start_date as previously indicated.